# Is there a way to assign a different changelist starting number in perforce?

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to assign a different changelists starting number in perforce?

We have 3 branches,  `dev`, `stage` and `release`.  Developers merge from `dev` to `stage` and then give the changelist number to the `release` manager to merge from `stage` to `release`.  Developers are supposed to give the Stage dev list number.  Once in a while they give the dev changelist number.  We want to be able to identify that easily.

For example, a changelist number is 59217.

If we could have the dev changelists start with an extra 0, we could easily tell a dev changelists 059217 from a stage 59217.

There has to be a way to do this. I searched online extensively and haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

If developers were on their own server you could potentially have their changelist numbers start at a higher value, but given that everyone is on the same server, changelist numbers are assigned in increasing order and it's not going to be possible to tell from the number itself what branch it affected.

Fortunately this information is easy to query given the change number.  Some example commands that might be useful:

```
p4 describe -s 59217
p4 files -m1 @=59217
p4 -Ztag -F %path% describe 59217
```